# C#, what to reference for .As<T>() method?

Tags: c#, linq

In [this RavenDB post](http://ayende.com/blog/152833/orders-search-in-ravendb), Ayende uses a `.As`call to "push" the data into the index's model. Was attempting the same thing in my my code, but it seems it's not a standard LINQ extension method?

What using, or reference, must I use to get access to .As() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source, it is defined in LinqExtensions.cs in the `Raven.Client.Linq` namespace.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate the quick answer!